# Hololens 2 windows sdk how to update

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I work on a Windows 11 machine, Unity 2022.1.21f1, VS2022 v17.3.6 that has windows sdks installed shown below. My H2 device OS is up to date (OS build 20348.1522).

[image]

I can build on Unity and release and deploy a project for H2 for version 10.0.10240.0
[image]

[image]

I can build a release app in Unity with version 10.0.22621.0 but I can't deploy to H2. When I try to deploy via VS2022 I get this error in VS2022:
[image]

```
Creating a new clean layout...
Copying files: Total 188 mb to layout...
Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
Registering the application to run from layout...
RemoteCommandException: Windows cannot install package XXX_1.0.0.0_arm64__ph1m9x8skttmg because this package is not compatible with the device. The package requires OS version 10.0.22621.0 or higher on the Windows.Holographic device family. The device is currently running OS version 10.0.20348.1522.

0x80073cfd
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80004005] Failed to register through new deployment pipeline.
```

In the H2 device the [OS is up to date (Windows Update)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-update-hololens). My sense is the error OS version refers to a Windows SDK update? if so how do I update it if not via Windows update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version here is the HoloLens OS version. **[10.0.20348.1522](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-release-notes#windows-holographic-version-22h1---october-2022-update)** is the current latest release version. And **10.0.22621** is the current preview version, please refer to [Insider preview for Microsoft HoloLens | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-insider). Usually, if there is no special requirement for **Minimum Platform Version**, just choose **10.0.10240.0**. Also, for Unity, the official recommendation is to use the LTS version, please refer to [Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version).